# DISTINCT по одному полю в запросе к нескольким таблицам

Tags: php, mysql

Ситуация такая: есть запрос:

```
/*В рабочем коде вместо 1 - id юзера*/
SELECT `schedule`.*, `events`.*, `repertoire`.`composition_name`, `repertoire`.`duration`, `repertoire`.`comments`
  FROM `schedule`, `events`, `repertoire`
  WHERE `schedule`.`event_id`=`events`.`event_id`
      AND (
            (`schedule`.`user_id`=1)
            OR
            (
              (`schedule`.`group_id` IN(SELECT `group_id` FROM `users_in_groups` WHERE `user_id`=1))
              AND
              (
                (`schedule`.`special_mark`='replace_me')
                AND
                (
                  (`schedule`.`user_id`<>1)
                  AND
                  /*TEST IT!!! (Чтобы не предлагало заменить человека в том же ивенте, где сам задействован)*/
                  (`schedule`.`event_id` NOT IN(SELECT `event_id` FROM `schedule` WHERE `user_id`=1))
                )
              )
            )
          )
      AND `events`.`event_start` BETWEEN '2018-08-14 00:00:00' AND '2018-08-21 00:00:00'
      AND `repertoire`.`composition_id`=`events`.`repertoire_id`
      ORDER BY `events`.`event_start` ASC
```

Возвращает набор строк, каждая из которых превращается при фетчинге в массив со следующими элементами (для удобства я здесь добавил префиксы с названиями таблиц)

```
schedule.node_id
schedule.user_id
schedule.group_id
schedule.event_id
schedule.custom_mark
schedule.is_disabled
schedule.special_mark
events.event_id
events.custom_group_id
events.repertoire_id
events.event_type
events.mark
events.event_start
events.event_end
events.background
events.place
events.conductor_id
repertoire.composition_name
repertoire.duration
repertoire.comments

//Если вдруг надо - в таблице users_in_groups три колонки:
users_in_groups.user_id
users_in_groups.group_id
users_in_groups.order_in_group
```

Суть запроса - найти юзеру все его выходы на работу + базовую информацию этих выходов + базовую информацию репертуара, где `schedule.group_id` равен `id` любой группы, в которой состоит пользователь. ПЛЮС подтянуть выходы, в которых он не задействован, но его коллега просит кого-нибудь его (коллегу) заменить.

Проект пишется для оркестра оперного театра. То есть, в переводе на человеческий с подстановкой данных - найти Иванову И.И. все его выходы + основную о них информацию (где, когда, и т.д.) + информацию, что ему предстоит играть, группа="гобой" или "инспектор оркестра" + вакантные выходы.

Ключевой момент здесь в том, что записей на один и тот же ивент и одного и того же юзера может быть несколько, и различаться они будут только `schedule.group_id`. Например, юзер помимо игры в оркестре задействован ещё в какой-то службе (инспектор, библиотекарь, монтировщик, etc.) или банде (сценический оркестр). А в результате при рендеринге будут дубликаты.

**НУЖНО**:

Каким-то образом сюда вставить `DISTINCT (schedule.event_id)` так, чтобы не пришлось выписывать через запятую каждое поле `events.*`. К сожалению, скьюлом я владею довольно посредственно, поэтому пока не вижу, как это сделать, а вариант с "при генерации карточек откладывать в массив event_id сгенерированной и перед генерацией следующей смотреть, чтобы не было дубликатов" кажется мне костыльным и оставлен на крайний случай. Хочется, всё же, сделать красиво...

---

P.S.: Т.к. руководство мне так и не предоставило до сих пор необходимые данные, чтобы закинуть их в БД и тестить (а создавать рыбные мне лень - потом заново делать ту же нудную работу для 150+ человек + репертуары и т.д.) - пока я 11 дней без тестов. НО: майскл-клиент не ругается на ошибки и отдаёт мне результат.

**ОГРОМЕННОЕ СПАСИБО!**

Comment: *А в результате при рендеринге будут дубликаты.* С точки зрения SQL дубликат - это запись, значения ВСЕХ полей которой равно значению полей записи-оригинала. Если хоть в одном поле хоть один бит не совпадает - это НЕ дубликаты. Точка. Если же Вы просто хотите при выводе не отображать значения части полей, если они равны значению физически предыдущей записи в потоке выходного набора, то делайте это именно при отображении - то есть уже на клиенте после получения от него данных.

Comment: То есть красиво сделать не получится :(

Comment: Ну почему? Описанная Вами структура вывода - это фактически дерево, а не таблица. Вот о выводе в форме дерева (или просто с разноуровневыми узлами аналогично структурированному Excel-файлу) и помыслите...

Comment: Можно попробовать сначала дистинктно вытащить event_id где group_id in(блаблабла) и (user_id=1 или вакантно), а потом на базе этого циклом вытаскивать остальную информацию

Comment: То есть вместо одного запроса выполнить кучу? ну если в условиях локального сервера БД это ещё туда-сюда (и всё равно провалишься по производительности), то для удалённого сервера это и вовсе безумие. И всё это - от нежелания немного поработать с полным и подробным набором данных, группируя и скрывая равные значения? да при том, что записи можно получить в уже удобном для этой операции порядке применением правильного ORDER BY? нет, дело Ваше, конечно...

Comment: Я немножко туповат...